# Optional reference in Dot Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, reference

I hope it may be a advanced concept in .Net 
My question is

**How to setup a program with optional reference?**

For example: Consider this case,
I've certain program which is capable exporting data to Excel.
This feature needs reference to Microsoft Office Excel (Some specific version)

Is there any way to write a program which run whether or not Excel installed, but some particular option (like reading or writing Excel) will be done only if Excel installed.

Program should run even when Excel is not installed.

Thanks.

Comment: you will have to dynamically load it using `Assembly.Load...`

Comment: Use a Try/Catch around an attempt to create an instance or worksheet (dynamically) and set a variable when it fails such as `HasExcel = False`.  Then it is just a bunch of `If HasExcel Then` statements in your code.

Comment: @Plutonix I don't think it's that simple since the app will not run if the Excel PIA cannot be loaded (without some code to handle that failure).

Comment: No, not for doing the Excel related stuff; but for program flow (ie not calling Excel related procedures), enabling buttons, menus and such is what I was offering it for.

Comment: The thing is - you DON'T NEED reference to Excel to export data. You can use Microsoft.Ace.Oledb to write data to excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic approaches.

1. `Assembly.Load` allows you to load arbitrary assemblies are runtime, inspect their contents, instantiate objects, call methods and so on. You would normally hide that behind things like an interface, a default implementation, a factory method and so on. Dependency Injection may rely on techniques like this.
2. You can use the Microsoft Managed Extensibility Framework, which does all this and more. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Excel is a bit of a special case, because it's accessible through COM automation, which provides some other opportunities and can add some other complications. You can usually build and run the program because the wrapper assemblies will be present, and handle execution failures at run-time if Excel is not.

Whichever way you go there can be quite a bit of code to write. There is not enough detail in the question to say much more, but it's not just a matter of setting an 'optional' flag.